# How do I fill an image half way through page even when resizing?

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio

I have searched everywhere before posting this*

I'm trying to have two images under each other. Each image takes half the page exactly, and the other half below it (2 different images). I tried looking everywhere but they say keep it as a background, although background you can only have 1 image. I also tried changing the width and height but it doesn't seem to work when resizing the window.

Can someone give me a hint please on what I should do?

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? Please read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing [mcve]s.

Comment: As I said i tried changing the width and height such as changing it to 100% or to auto

Comment: As I said: where's your code. Please read the 2 pages I linked to above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following `css` with the images you want to cover half the page.. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BFG/mc8xbc87/7/) link so that you can resize the HTML-output to see if it's what you're going for.

```css
#img1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh; /* 50% of the view-height */
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}

#img2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh; /* 50% of the view-height */
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
```

:

Answer (score 0):

```css
#m2 {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/nature/');
  padding:20%;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-size: cover;
}

#m3 {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/');
  padding:20%;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="m2"></div>
<div id="m3"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rashivkp/ffevt4bg/